# CodeDom + Assembly.Load throws a BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, codedom, badimageformatexception

I'm trying to execute a file from a given byte array, which works great:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Location\program.exe");
MessageBox.Show(bytes.Length) // The same size for both the VS compiled and CodeDom compiled application
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes); //Throws exception when compiled with CodeDOM
```

This code compiles and runs fine from within an application I generated with Visual studio.

However, when I add this piece of code to an application I generated with CodeDOM, it throws a BadImageException.

The CodeDOM generated application reads the bytes fine, because both versions output the same byte[] length.

I tried changing the target framework from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.5, I tried changing the target architecture, but I could not get it to work.

What could cause this exception?

Comment: It possibly because of 64bit and 32bit conflict. You may try to load assembly in different type of architecture. Either your assembly is issue or program that load that assembly is problem

Comment: I set the target architecture for the assembly to x86 and now the codeDOM application can load it without a problem, thanks! Why, however, does the application generated with VS2012 not have this problem?

Comment: No it is not like that. It is how you build your project. I will describe detail in answer so scenario can helpful to other.

Comment: What is not like what? The application that I built with VS ran the 'any cpu' assembly fine, while the CodeDOM generated application can only run 'x86' on my 64-bit system?

Comment: There is no point in doing this at all, use CompilerResults.CompiledAssembly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Assembly architecture and Application that load assembly.

So if application build with X64 and if It try to load assembly with X86 then it create problem.This apply in opposite case as well.

Other scenario is that when application build with Visual studio then default option is Any CPU.

In this case when process is 64 bit it will load as 64 bit and when application is 32 bit it is load as 32 bit. We restrict this way because some unmanaged resource works under special environment.

I encounter such problem with Oracle client of .net.